# How to rewrite a URL using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am a beginner in url rewriting.

I have a url like this

http://www.sitename.com/subpages/detail.php?id=21-0043-052&car_name=abc

I want to redirect this site to

http://www.qualitextrading.com/vehicle-detail.php?id=21-0043-052&car_name=abc

Please how I can write this in .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `mod_rewrite` enabled:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sitename.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^\/subpages\/detail\.php(*.?)$ http://www.qualitextrading.com/vehicle-detail.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

This turns on rewriting for this area, then checks if the HTTP_HOST is correct, then rewrites the URL and passes on the query string (default behavior of `mod_rewrite` passes on query string automatically).

Comment: I copied the same what you typed by replacing the sitename but no result. i checked mod_rewrite is on as other rewrite rules are working

Comment: now i put your changed code and the site go blank with following errorInternal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: You need to check `/var/log/apache2/errors.log` like with any other `Internal Server Error`. You may need to escape the `.` in the string.